# How to convert x-www-url-encoded body to an array of object in JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, parsing, urlencode

Request body received in URL encoded format(sourceUrl) from the client, need to convert it to array of object(Basket) in javascript

```
const sourceUrl= 'Basket%5B0%5D%5BId%5D=383293820&Basket%5B0%5D%5BDescription%5D=Mi%2010%2064GB%20Gold&Basket%5B0%5D%5BQuantity%5D=1&Basket%5B0%5D%5BTotalPrice%5D=3000&Basket%5B0%5D%5BCategory%5D=Smartphone&Basket%5B1%5D%5BId%5D=384567'
```

```
Target obj array: 
Basket = [
           { 
             Id: 383293820,
             Description: Mi 10 64GB Gold,
             Quantity: 1,
             TotalPrice: 3000,
             Category: Smartphone
           },
           {
             Id: 384567
           },
           
           ]
```

Comment: In what language? I see that your post is tagged with javascript, but "string" isnt a keyword in javascript

Comment: Use the available body parser for form/urlencoded, that gets you an actual data object - and then you encode that _as_ JSON again. Where's the actual problem with that?

Comment: There's no such thing as a "JSON Object". What you have shown there is an array of objects.